# SQL Server read xml values as empty strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, sqlxml

I have the following c# class

```
public class Data
{
    public string A {get;set;}
    public string B {get;set;}
    public string C {get;set;}
}
```

I create an instance of this in my code:

```
var d = new Data { A = "abc", B = string.Empty, C = null};
```

I need to convert this to XML and pass it to a sproc in SQL Server 2008.

I do this using:

```
var xml = new XElement("Data",
    new XElement("A", d.A),
    new XElement("B", d.B),
    new XElement("C", d.C));
```

The resultant XML in the sproc is:

```
<Data>
    <A>abc</A>
    <B></B>
    <C />
</Data>
```

So, there's a difference between an empty string an a null value.

Then in SQL, I'm using the following syntax to read the XML:

```
INSERT INTO #myTable
SELECT 
  nref.value('(A/text())[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') [A],
  nref.value('(B/text())[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') [B],
  nref.value('(C/text())[1]', 'uniqueidentifier') [C],
FROM @DataXml.nodes('/Data') AS R(nref);
```

But this is providing me with B and C both as NULL, where B should be empty string.

How can I adapt this to ensure that nulls remain as nulls and empty strings remain as empty strings?

Thanks

Comment: Where you said "rad the xml" do you mean "read the xml"?

Comment: Why do you need to convert it to XML to pass to the stored proc, only to break it out of XML back into discrete fields?  Just pass the discrete values to the stored proc...

Comment: Max, yes for "rad" read "read".  The XML in this message was very simplistic, my actual XML is far more complicated and allows me to pass a batch of objects to my sproc which can then iterate through them.

Answer (score 2):

XElement constructor may treat NULL and empty differently, but the XML spec considers < X /> and < X>< /X> to be identical.  SQL server XQuery treats them identically as well.

If you want SQL server to distinguish between empty & null elements, you need to exclude the null element completely when you construct the XML in your C# code.  For example, the below treats element B as empty & element C as NULL, since it's missing:

```
declare @x xml = 
'<Data><A>abc</A><B></B></Data>'

SELECT 
  nref.value('(A/text())[1]', 'varchar') [A],
  isnull(nref.value('(B/text())[1]', 'varchar'), case when nref.exist('./B') = 1 then '' end) [B],
  isnull(nref.value('(C/text())[1]', 'varchar'), case when nref.exist('./C') = 1 then '' end) [C]
FROM @x.nodes('/Data') AS R(nref);
```

Comment: Your xml node selector does not use the "text()" method and so is likely to return expected results when there are child elements, e.g. when @x = '<Data><A>abc</A><B></B><D><D1>d1</D1><D2>d2</D2></D></Data>'.  So when you do use the text() method (e.g. "nref.value('(B/text())[1]', 'varchar(10)') [B]") then values for B and C are both returned as NULL.

Comment: @DrGriff You are correct, I didn't consider that.  Though the main point I was trying to make is that < X /> and < X>< /X> are *identical in meaning*, per the XML spec.  So you would need to actually exclude the element (when you construct the XML in your C# code) to signify NULL vs. empty.  Anyway, I edited the answer to offer one possible solution based on EXIST method.  Hope it helps.

Comment: don't know why this one was downvoted, here's my upvote :) It's not very elegant way to do this, but it should work